# How to determine if a user views a notification on lock screen by using default view button

Tags: ios, push-notification, notifications, apple-push-notifications, swift4

I have been working with Rich Push Notifications (IOS)

and want to know is there any way to determine if a user views a notification on lock screen by default view button

Answer (score 0):

You can't know if the user "viewed" the notification external to your app but you can know a few other things:

- If the notification was sent
- If it was received by the phone
- If the user clicked on the notification

The second and third items can be tracked in AppDelegate through this method:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping() -> Void) {
```